# XAML Initiate animation from button

Tags: c#, xaml

How can the color animation below be triggered by clicking the button, without using any code-behind?

I know how to start an animation procedurally - but I'd like to keep everything in XAML here.

Currently the animation runs all the time, because it is triggered by the loading of the `Grid` it is contained in.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="ChangingBrush"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                            From="White"
                            To="Blue"
                            Duration="0:0:2"
                            AutoReverse="True"
                            RepeatBehavior="Forever"></ColorAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>
        <Button
            Grid.Row="0">Do Work</Button>
        <Image Grid.Row="1">
            <Image.Source>
                <DrawingImage>
                    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                        <GeometryDrawing>
                            <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="ChangingBrush" Color="LightBlue"></SolidColorBrush>
                            </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"></EllipseGeometry>
                            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        </GeometryDrawing>
                    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                </DrawingImage>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your button a name and bind the trigger to it. If you do not want it to keep repeating, then replace `RepeatBehavior="Forever"></ColorAnimation>` with something like `RepeatBehavior="1x"></ColorAnimation>` or [look here for further options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753367(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="BeginButton">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="ChangingBrush"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                            From="White"
                            To="Blue"
                            Duration="0:0:2"
                            AutoReverse="True"
                            RepeatBehavior="Forever"></ColorAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>
        <Button
            Name="BeginButton"
            Grid.Row="0">Do Work</Button>
        <Image Grid.Row="1">
            <Image.Source>
                <DrawingImage>
                    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                        <GeometryDrawing>
                            <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="ChangingBrush" Color="LightBlue"></SolidColorBrush>
                            </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"></EllipseGeometry>
                            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        </GeometryDrawing>
                    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                </DrawingImage>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I didn't pay attention to the specific example when I provided another as answer so I've del'd mine and +1 to this instead.